# Toggle between two leds

Tags: transistors, led, electrical

I am designing a circuit with not a lot of knowledge in electronics and I am close to finishing it. The finishing part remains.

So, I have got a logic 1 or 0 from  comp op amp and based upon that one of two LEDs should be on. One LED is always on. First one if its HIGH, second one if its LOW.

Both LEDs shouldn't be on at the same time.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You're "designing" yet I do not see a schematic. You're just describing what you want. That's not "designing a circuit". And if you say: "Oh, yeah, I'm supposed to design it" then it would be a homework question so I'd ask: "what have you tried?".

Answer (score 1):

You can make a NOT function via a transistor (e.g. see [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/logic_4.html)).
Excerpt:

> A simple 2-input logic NOT gate can be constructed using a RTL
>   Resistor-transistor switches as shown below with the input connected
>   directly to the transistor base. The transistor must be saturated “ON”
>   for an inverted output “OFF” at Q.

[image]

Than you can lead your output signal (for HIGH) to a resistor and the HIGH LED, and the same output signal through the NOT circuit and a resistor to the LOW LED.